# c++ wrong representation of a number fitting in double

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision

look at this snipped:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //double a = 15670.1;
    //a += 110420;
    double a = 1.1;
    a += 110420;
    printf("%f\n",a);
    cout << a << endl;
    a = 1.1;
    a += 11042;
    printf("%f\n",a);
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

and result is:

```
110421.100000
110421
11043.100000
11043.1
```

as it seems `printf` works correctly but what is wrong with cout in the first test case? it is ommiting the 0.1 and why is this ( cout ) correct in the second test case?

Answer (score 2):

By default, a C++ stream formats floating-point values to 6 significant figures, while `printf`, with `%f`, formats them to 6 decimal places.

You can use `std::setprecision` (declared in `<iomanip>`) to specify a higher precision:

```
cout << setprecision(7) << a << endl; // 110421.1
```

Comment: @Pooya: In the second case, 6 significant figures are enough give the expected value. In the first, you need 7.

Comment: could you explain it more?

Comment: @Pooya digits count, dot is not a digit

Comment: @Pooya: Explain significant figures? That's basic maths: http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/number/roundestimaterev3.shtml

Comment: The answer really doesn't address the question, because in both cases, the precision is set to 6.  The difference is in the different output formats (which is only hinted about), and the way they process precision.

Comment: @MikeSeymour no, I mean why is set to 6 significant figures? it may lead to misjudge according to the logs.

Comment: @JamesKanze: indeed, the difference is the interpretation of "precision" to mean either "decimal places" or "significant figures", as my answer says.

Comment: @Pooya: 6 is as good as any other arbitrary default. If you don't like the default, then override it.

Answer (score 0):

The precision of cout is too low by default. You can increase it by using `setprecision()`. See the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //double a = 15670.1;
    //a += 110420;
    double a = 1.1;
    a += 110420;
    printf("%f\n",a);
    cout << setprecision(20) << a << endl;
    a = 1.1;
    a += 11042;
    printf("%f\n",a);
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The reason that the second test case is correct is simply that you use fewer significant digits there.

Comment: You have fewer significant digits there.

Answer (score 0):

default precision for double is 6. You can inspect this using  6. You can inspect this using precision():

```
std::streamsize ss = std::cout.precision();
std::cout << "Initial precision = " << ss << '\n';
```

In your example:

```
110421.100000        // oops, truncated to 6 digits, gives 110421 printed

11043.100000         // oops, truncated to 6 **digits**, thus 110431 printed
```

You can now adjust the precision with setprecision(int):

```
cout << setprecision(10) << a << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get different results is because you ask for
different things.  In the `printf`, you're asking for a fixed
format.  With `std::cout`, you're asking for a variable format,
corresponding to `"%g"` in `printf`.  If you set `std::cout` to
fixed format, with e.g.:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << a;
```

You should see the same thing as with `printf( "%f", a )`.

For what it's worth, the output precision defaults to 6 in both
cases (`printf` and `std::cout`).  But precision means different
things according to the format: in the varying format
corresponding to `"%g"`, it means the total number of
significant digits; in the other formats (fixed and scientific),
it means the number of digits after the decimal; in the case of
fixed, that can be a signficant difference.

(Of course, at some point, you'll run out of precision in the
internal foramt.)

Finally, in a large application, you'll normally define you're
own manipulators, things like `degrees` or `distance` or
`interestRate`; the manipulator will set a number of different
formatting options, so that when the boss decides that you have
to display degrees with more precision, you only have to change
the manipulator, and not go through the entire code base trying
to figure out which `"%f"` correspond to degrees.